# Magento Add to Cart just redirecting to home page no adding

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, addtocart

Regular products work just fine in store but configurable products don't.\

When you click on "Add To Cart" on a `configurable product it just tries loading for about 5 seconds` and then redirects you to `home page` without adding to cart.

Comment: No javascript errors that I can tell  either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debug all flow for adding product to cart. In process I found that `collectTotal` function of quote is not setting price and continuously loops to bug which make redirect to home page. 
Validation for configurable product is failed in this file

> /store/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Subselect.php

This file on line number 117 having this function call on configurable  product Item validation

`if (parent::validate($item)) {`

which is somehow because this `validate($item)` function is not in it parent class.

Instead this `validate($item)` is in Class `Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine` so modified it to

`if (Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine::validate($item)) {`

Answer (score 1):

1- Are you using any module for configurable products?
2- Maybe send bad information with configurable products because it send the data as an array, and it depends of the type of product.(this is easy to program).
3- Any conflict with cart before?

Could post some code like the add of the button and the response.

Comment: http://www.fantomworks.com/store/ss-pass.html here is an example of what's going on. Try adding that item to the cart.

Comment: and to answer your questions I'm not using any modules. There has been no conflict in the past. Nothing in the logs.

Comment: but you can add http://www.fantomworks.com/store/drs-patch-8644.html to the cart without issue